# Bottom tabs not filling the screen

Tags: android, tabs, tabactivity

I'm developing an application that requires bottom tabs. I've got the tabs in their place but there's an empty space between the tabs and the bottom,left and right of the screen.
I downloaded a sample code which looks exactly how I want my tabs but the spaces keep on appearing.

My Application:
http://postimg.org/image/6ft0v2qyn/

How I want my tabs to look:
http://postimg.org/image/az9l93ymx/

Sorry I cant post images directly because I don't have enough reputation.

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Function for adding the tabs:

```
private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
        //tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
```

Passing parameters for the function:

```
addTab("Send News", R.drawable.icon_sendnews, SendNewsActivity.class);
```

SOLVED: The tabHost had a 5dp padding, I don't know where it came from but when I removed it, the tabs took the shape I wanted :D
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Have you read this ? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: how u inserting tabs?

Comment: @2Dee : I have read it before, I don't even like bottom tabs but it's required for this application :/

Comment: @Farhan : I edited the post with some code

Answer (score 0):

Possibly in your fragment Layout you have not removed **margins**.

Comment: Which fragment layout? For each tab I'm using a different type of layout called from their respective classes.